# Creating PHP counter/rules for Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap grid is 910px spanning 15 columns. Each post in my Wordpress loop spans 5 columns.

Here's the static code:

```
<div class="container">     

    <div class="row">

        <div class="span5">
            <p>Post title and image</p>
        </div>

        <div class="span5">
            <p>Post title and image</p>
        </div>

        <div class="span5">
            <p>Post title and image</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And then here's roughly how it would look with the loop:

```
<div class="container">     

    <?php theloop; ?>

</div>
```

Unless there's a better way, I think I want to tell Wordpress to say:

- Make a variable $counter
- For every post, increase the value by one
- Where the value is one, start the post with `div class="row"`
- Where the value is three, start the post with `</div>` (closing the row)
- Reset $counter to zero after reaching three and start again

I don't know how to do this. I've asked for help with a similar issue before but I'm totally new to PHP, I'd really appreciate a clear breakdown and explanation.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like another use-case for the [`TableIterator`](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/some-php-iterator-fun/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it somehow like this:

```
 <?php 
 $i=1;
 echo '<div class="row">';
 if (have_posts()) : ?>
           <?php while (have_posts()) :   
           // do stuff ...
           the_post();
           if($i % 3 == 0)
               echo '</div><div class="row">';
           $i++; endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I didn't test it, but somehow like this. Use the [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) function.